# Fuzzy date parsing with Java

Tags: java, fuzzy, date-parsing

Are there any libraries for Java that allow you to interpret dates like "Yesterday", "Next Monday", ...

Comment: Do you mean the string literals, or just something that makes it easy to walk a date back a day or figure out the date of the first Monday in the future, but not providing the text parsing of a literal "Next Monday?"

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/). Feel free to fork it and modify its [grammar](https://github.com/joestelmach/natty/blob/master/src/main/antlr3/com/joestelmach/natty/generated/DateParser.g).

Comment: Might be worth noting that as of March 2021 (this comment), Natty has not been updated for 4 years.

https://github.com/joestelmach/natty

Answer (score 2):

[Su-time](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml) from stanford is your (and my) friend.

Answer (score 1):

A library like [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is probably as close as you're gonna get.  It doesn't convert strings, but offers much more functionality than the Java default `Date` class.

Here is a [utility class](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Swing-Library/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/calendar/DateUtils.java.htm) that provides some of the functions you're looking for, but again without fuzzy string conversion.